# To clear(reset) dynamically generated picture box

Tags: c#, winforms

```
` private void getbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // To generate Images
        {
            if (cmbDocType.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {

                if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    con.Open();
                string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString());
                string FileNamePath = directory + "MembersDocuments\\" + GlobalValues.Member_ID + "\\" + cmbDocType.Text;
                string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(FileNamePath);
                if (list.Length > 0)
                {
                    label1.Text = "";
                    PictureBox[] picturebox = new PictureBox[list.Length];
                    int y = 0;

                    for (int index = 0; index < picturebox.Length; index++)
                    {
                        picturebox[index] = new PictureBox();

                        if (x % 3 == 0)
                        {
                            y = y + 150; // 3 images per rows, first image will be at (20,150)
                            x = 0;
                        }
                        picturebox[index].Location = new Point(x * 230 + 20, y);
                        picturebox[index].Size = new Size(200, 150);
                        x++;

                        picturebox[index].Size = new Size(200, 100);
                        picturebox[index].Image = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
                        picturebox[index].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                        picturebox[index].Click += new EventHandler(picturebox_Click);

                        cmbDocType_SelectedIndexChanged(picturebox[index], e);
                        this.Controls.Add(picturebox[index]);

                    }

                }

                else
                {
                    label1.Text = "No Images to display";
                    label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }

                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select the Document Type");
            }


        }
            `
```

Can anyone tell me how to clear previous images(result of first call) in dynamically created pictureboxes on a new call. On making new call,previous images should not be seen..in c#
I have combobox named Type.
lets say if i have Aminals,Birds in my Combobox.
on first call pictures of animals will be displayed and on choosing combobox for second time i.e birds, Pictures of Both the types are getting displayed.
i Need to display Pictures of single type at a time. in c#
Thanks;

Comment: Use `DataGridView` with `DataGridViewImageColumn` instead of dynamically created PictureBoxes. Where you can set new images just by one line `yourDataGridView.DataSource = collectionOfImages`

Comment: Store those dynamically create Picturenoxes in a List<PictureBo>! Then you clear clear the images (sdon't forget to also Dispose of them!!!) or delete the PBs themselves..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by TaW in the comments:

```
private List<PictureBox> PBs = new List<PictureBox>();

private void getbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // To generate Images
{
    if (cmbDocType.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        foreach(PictureBox pb in PBs)
        {
            pb.Dispose();
        }
        PBs.Clear();

        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Open();
        string directory = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString());
        string FileNamePath = directory + "MembersDocuments\\" + GlobalValues.Member_ID + "\\" + cmbDocType.Text;
        string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(FileNamePath);
        if (list.Length > 0)
        {
            label1.Text = "";
            PictureBox PB;
            int y = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < list.Length; index++)
            {
                PB = new PictureBox();

                if (x % 3 == 0)
                {
                    y = y + 150; // 3 images per rows, first image will be at (20,150)
                    x = 0;
                }
                PB.Location = new Point(x * 230 + 20, y);
                PB.Size = new Size(200, 150);
                x++;

                PB.Size = new Size(200, 100);
                PB.Image = Image.FromFile(list[index]);
                PB.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                PB.Click += new EventHandler(picturebox_Click);
                PBs.Add(PB);
                this.Controls.Add(PB)
                cmbDocType_SelectedIndexChanged(PB, e);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            label1.Text = "No Images to display";
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select the Document Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Idle_Mind, TaW and Fabio for your Solutions.Now it Works fine.